# Value of type 'DirectoryInfo' cannot be converted to 'String'

Tags: vb.net, system.io.directory

I am trying to start a .exe file in a parent folder to which my .exe file is in.

Unfortunately when doing:

```
dir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory))
```

The program gives me an error:

> Value type of 'DirectoryInfo' cannot be converted to 'String'.

It works perfectly with `CurrentDirectory`, but doesn't with `GetParent`. Not even if I just put:

```
dir = Directory.GetParent("")
```

I would think they both return the same file type but Visual Studio tells me (when shading over the `GetParent` method) that `GetParent` returns a `DirectoryInfo` value.

Is there any way of converting this to a string, or being able to use it to my needs?

Answer (score 0):

[`Directory.GetParent` Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [`DirectoryInfo` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) instance.

I'd expect you can get the directory name using the [`DirectoryInfo.FullName` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a string.

Something like:

```
dir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())).FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

[Directory.GetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `DirectoryInfo` class and as the error says this cannot be converted to string.

Instead what you want to do is declare a variable to hold the `DirectoryInfo` and then access the properties from it, specifically the [FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
Dim dirInfo As DirectoryInfo = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory)
Dim path As String = dirInfo.FullName
```

This of course can be done with a one liner but for clarification I thought it would help you to break it up. For a one liner use:

```
Dim dir As String = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory).FullName
```

In both cases the output is:

> C:\Development\VS2013\WindowsApplication1\bin